# PhpStorm editing multiple selection

Tags: arrays, phpstorm

I'm wondering about way to edit multiple selections but with different texts

For example:

```
arr=['hi','i','am','your','array','can','change','me','quickly','please']

arr=['test1','text','foo','test','fast','yes','test2','test3','text2','text3']
```

I have array of ten elements and I want to change them all with different texts.

Ordinary way to select one then change it. If you use multiple selections all of them are replaced with the same new text.

The question there: any way to change them faster?

I think there may be a way to change it like Emmet in HTML when you enter Emmet code PhpStorm convert it and take you inside red box in each element to write inside it one by one.

Comment: why -1 ?????
I searched for hours and haven't find answer
and here in stackoverflow -in the community of developers- someone come and give negative rating for the question
so to that man do you have answer for my question ???
i am feeling sham

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution to make it easily to edit the array

just using the find `ctrl+f` and then use `f3` to get next value to edit

in the search we can enter the regular expression that will find any matched values

```
(?<=')\w+(?=')|(?<=,)\w+(?=,)|(?<=\[)\w+(?=,)|(?<=,)\w+(?=])
```

`(?<=')\w+(?=')` : any text inside single quotes symbol ' can be changed double "

`(?<=,)\w+(?=,)`: any word between commas for numbers and variables in the array

`(?<=\[)\w+(?=,)`: the first element of the array if it as number or variable

`(?<=,)\w+(?=])` : the last element in the array if it as number or variable

`|` : or operator